# How to send FormData with another FormControl using Reactive form in angular 6?

Tags: angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I make a form with some fields like email user name and avatar using reactive form of angular 6. I know i need form data to upload image, but i dont know how to using it with reactive form in angular 6. Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="yourForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
   <input type="text" formControlName="email"> <br>
   <input (change)="uploadDocument($event)" type="file" accept=".png, .pdf, .jpg, .jpeg"> <br>
   <input (change)="onSubmit()" type="submit" value="Send file">
</form>
```

in your `app.component.html`, then:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  yourForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.yourForm = this.fb.group({
      email: [''],
      file: ['']
    });
  }

  uploadDocument(event: any) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        this.yourForm.get('file').setValue(event.target.files[0]);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    const uploadData = new FormData();
    uploadData.append('email', this.yourForm.get('email').value);
    uploadData.append('file', this.yourForm.get('file').value);
    this.http.post('your-route', uploadData);
  }
}
```

in your `app.component.ts`, and:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

in your `app.module.ts` file.
Also, don't forget to configure the route in line `this.http.post('your-route', uploadData);`.

Comment: thanks for the response i already do the same like you :d but one more question, how can i send formdata with effect in ngrx store?

Comment: I think that it must be combination of the following: `constructor(private store: Store<any>) {}` and `const source = this.store.pipe(select('your select function'))` and `source.subscribe(data=>  uploadData.append('field', data.field); )`. You aslo can use `forkJoin` function from `rxjs` when pulling several fields out of the store.

Comment: can i just simple call action post from effect ?

Comment: I did't use `@ngrx/effects`, but according to [example](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/README.md) it is possible.